# Regarding STL container

Tags: c++, linux

I am facing an issue in c++ STL container map.

```
class c1 {

map<int , vector<entity>>  mapobject   //where entity is a structure

c1{

    entity er;
    er.entityId = 1;
    er.nameId = 1; 

    std::vector<entity> record;
    record.push_back(er);

    mapobject.insert(std::pair<int,std::vector<entity>>(1,record));

}
}
```

The problem which i am facing from the above code is , outside the constructor , all the strcuture fields contains garbage values. Will the class level variable -  map not deep copy the contents ?

Please help me in this

--kumar

Comment: Your code is very incorrect. What's with c1, where's your function, why is the map declaration a string?

Comment: What does `entity` look like?

Comment: Aside from the wide-ranging selection of syntax errors above, are you *sure* the fields contain junk? You aren't just trying to debug a release-mode build, are you?

Comment: could you please fix the code so it is valid C++?

Comment: I think this needs to be edited to become a real question. The code that's given can't possibly compile. Any code he's running is clearly different from what's posted here. Trying to guess about problems in code we can't even see is a futile exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a copy-constructor for `entity`:

```
class entity
{
public:
    entity(const entity& other)
    {}
};
```

C++ does not deep-copy objects by default. There are also some syntax errors in your code:

```
class c1 {

map<int , vector<entity>>  mapobject;   //missing semicolon

c1 () { //missing parameter list

    entity er;
    er.entityId = 1;
    er.nameId = 1; 

    std::vector<entity> record;
    record.push_back(er);

    mapobject.insert(std::pair<int,std::vector<entity>>(1,record));

}
}; //missing semicolon
```

Comment: If entity really does contain just two integer members though, the default copy constructor will be fine. Also, the above won't compile unless a space is added in the mapObject declaration between the closing angle brackets. (Unless this is C++11?)

Comment: i have implemented copy constructor.still it contains garbage values after the constructor.

Comment: It will work if entity is a structure and all of the fields are POD, too.

Comment: Yes..my entity structure is POD only. Below are my structure    '**struct entity { int entityid ; int nameid;  }**'

Comment: @muthukumar It works for me. How do you know the fields contain garbage values? Are you printing the values?

Comment: i am debugging using eclipse gdp debugger in linux platform

Comment: @muthukumar what if you try to output the values?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have shown would be fine if all of the syntax errors are corrected. Are you sure that the data really is "garbage" "outside the constructor"? If you are inspecting an instance of c1 in the debugger but have built a release-mode build, it would appear to contain junk. That would just be an artefact of debugging in that way.